# Django (Password_change) doesn't work url

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django book named by (Django for beginners)

I have a problem with password _change
Below my code from **urls.py**

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path,include 

urlpatterns = [
   path('',include('pages.urls')),
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('users/', include('users.urls')),
   path('users/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Next is **password_change_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %}
Password Change
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   <h1>Password change</h1>
   <p>Please enter your old password, for security's sake, and then enter your
      new password twice so we can verify you typed it in correctly.</p>
   <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Change my password">
   </form>  
{% endblock %}
```

my content does'nt linking to **password_change_form.html**
Via versa linking to *password_change* from Django adminstration

Comment: To confirm, when you use the change password functionality in admin, your template isn't being loaded, is that what your problem is?

Comment: year. that template(password_change_form) isn't being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Crete an app named 'registration'

```
python manage.py startapp registration
```

2. Set it in the first position of your installed Apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'registration',
    ....
]
```

3. Inside the app 'registration', create a the folder 'templates/registration'
4. Inside the folder created in the previous step, you can now set all your custom templates, 'password_change_form.html', 'password_change_done.html', etc....
5. import the urls inside the main urls, I would prefer using like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ... # your urls
   path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```